# Warning in Adobe Air for iOS:ActionScript contained in externally loaded SWF files will be ignored on iOS devices

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, swfupload

I am trying to download an external swf with (as3 file) actionscript. I am using Adobe Air to publish to iOS.

On publishing it in iOS, I am getting following warning - **"ActionScript contained in externally loaded SWF files will be ignored on iOS devices"**

I have uploaded a demo zip file with my code. Plz have a look.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1C7E2FDD9D014F66!134&authkey=!APGyYi0V2b_EjWQ&ithint=file%2c.zip

I am using adobe flash professional cs6. Air SDK version is 13.0.0.83

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You haven't asked the question yet, what is the matter? This warning means that on iOS you can;t have SWF's with code as this code will not work after loading - thus no modules or shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Packaging and loading multiple SWFs in AIR apps on iOS](http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/09/packaging-and-loading-multiple-swfs-in-air-apps-on-ios/):

> AIR on iOS requires that all the ActionScript code of an application be present in the main SWF or the root SWF.
>
> [image: swf-loading]

Dynamically loading a remote SWF that contains ActionScript code will not work on iOS; nor  will embedding SWFs using the `[Embed]` meta tag.

Comment: For the record, there are two reasons for this. 1) Apple does not allow externally loaded code, for any app under any circumstance. It is a security issue. There is no way around it. 2) Even if Apple did allow it, AIR apps are cross-compiled to Objective-C. Apple does not allow runtime interpreters, so your app isn't actually running as AS3 and does not actually have the AIR runtime included. There would be no mechanism within the app that could possibly run the loaded AS3

Answer (score 0):

I was using Adobe Flash Professional CS6 thats why it was giving as warning.Now i am using Adobe Flash Professional CC then its working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe has introduced a way to load secondary .swfs with code.

http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2013/03/08/external-hosting-of-secondary-swfs-for-air-apps-on-ios/

They get around the Apple limitation by embedding the AS in the app at build time -- but not the assets. When the .swf is loaded dynamically, it loads the assets and reunites it with the code. A great way to keep app file size down.